# Unstaged Changes in GIT

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). I have finished working on a hotfix and then in GIT flow when I click on Finish Hotfix I get the error message

> Working tree contains unstaged changes. Aborting.

I would like to know why I am getting this? The hotfix does have new files, would the new files be a cause for this? Is there anyway to find out what file is causing this?

Comment: commit your changes first

Comment: should i commit my changes then close the hotfix ?

Comment: i don't work in sourcetree but the message is due to uncommitted changes. please add all the files and changes, then commit and close the hotfix branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (unstaged changes) does not only happen when you have new files, but also if you have changed files. Staging refers to adding them to the index (before commit). In sourcetree, this is done with the "Add" button, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the feature (branch), push it, then another right click in the same feature and merge it when finish that, just delete it.